# Does $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text da \ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text db \ e^{i u (a^2-b^2) - v(a^2-b^2)^2}a^p b^q$ converge?

Tags: improper-integrals

I'm trying to solve

\begin{equation}
S_{p,q}:=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text da \ 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text db \ 
\exp \Big[i u (a^2-b^2) - v(a^2-b^2)^2\Big]
a^p b^q
\end{equation}
with positive real valued constants $u$ and $v$ for all cases where $p+q\le4$. Its easy to show that $S$ vanishes if either $p$ or $q$ is odd. Lets also notice, that for $v \rightarrow 0$ the integral can be written as the product of two integrals which both converge. So i would expect that for $v>0$ the integral also converges, because a nonvanishing $v$ makes the integrand smaller.

Because Mathematica can not solve this integral, I tried the following transformations. First we substitute $a \rightarrow x(a):=a^2$ and $b \rightarrow y(b):=b^2$ which leads to
\begin{equation}
S_{p,q} 
= 
\int_0^\infty \text dx \ 
\int_0^\infty \text dy \ 
\exp\Big[iu(x-y) -v (x-y)^2\Big]
x^{(p-1)/2} y^{(q-1)/2}.
\end{equation}

My next transformation was setting
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}g\\h\end{pmatrix}
:=
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
which gives
\begin{equation}
S_{p,q} 
=
\frac 1 {|-2|}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text d h \ 
\exp \left(iuh-vh^2\right)
\int_{|h|}^\infty \text d g \ 
\left(\frac {g+h}2\right)^{(p-1)/2}
\left(\frac {g-h}2\right)^{(q-1)/2}.
\end{equation}
The transformation of the limits can easily be seen, when you note, that in the $x-y-$ System, the integral goes over the upper right quadrant. The $g-h-$ System is rotated by 45° relative to the $x-y-$ System. So if you let  $h$ run over all real numbers, $g$ has to be greater or equal to $|h|$ for $(x,y)$ being in the upper right quadrant.

Now for all interesting cases (where $p+q \le 4$) the second integral diverges. My question is: Does this also mean, that $S$ diverges? If so, why does $S$ for $v \rightarrow 0$ converge? And if not, do you have an idea how to solve this integral?

Comment: If $S$ diverges for $v > 0$ (and it indeed seems so), then what does the limit $S$ as $v \to 0^+$ even mean? It seems to me that you should distinguish the value of $S$ at $v = 0$ and the limit of $S$ as $v \to 0^+$. Anyway, the integral might be made meaningful if we adopt certain regularization procedure.